# Logic error when averaging several different numbers and outputting the result

Tags: c, math

I'm just beginning C, and I am encountering a logic error when trying to output the average of numbers entered. I will provide the source code of the program below.

```
// integer_sequence_avg.c
// Inputs a sequence of integers then averages them and outputs the result after the sentinel value "9999" is entered.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // initializaiton
    int addend = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int average;
    unsigned int counter;
    
    for (addend; addend != 9999; ++counter) {   
        printf("%s", "Enter an integer to be averaged. Enter \"9999\" when you want to receive the average: "); // prompt to enter integers to be averaged
        scanf("%d", &addend); // scans input into variable to be added to sum
        
        if (addend != 9999) {
            sum += addend; // Adds addend to sum
        }
    }
    
    if (counter != 0) {
        average = sum / counter; // Calculates average
        
        printf("\nThe average of the integers added was %d\n\n", average); // Outputs average of numbers entered
    } else {
        printf("\nNo integers were entered.\n\n"); // Outputs that no integers were entered
    }
    
    system("pause");
    
    return 0;
}
```

logic error screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwwaa.png

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 1):

- `counter` is incremented without being initialized. This invoked *undefined behavior*.
- `counter` is incremented even when `addend != 9999` is false.
- Return values of `scanf()` should be checked to see if it successfully read things.

Instead of this

```
    unsigned int counter;
    
    for (addend; addend != 9999; ++counter) {   
        printf("%s", "Enter an integer to be averaged. Enter \"9999\" when you want to receive the average: "); // prompt to enter integers to be averaged
        scanf("%d", &addend); // scans input into variable to be added to sum
        
        if (addend != 9999) {
            sum += addend; // Adds addend to sum
        }
    }
```

Try this:

```
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    
    while ( addend != 9999 ) {   
        printf("%s", "Enter an integer to be averaged. Enter \"9999\" when you want to receive the average: "); // prompt to enter integers to be averaged
        if (scanf("%d", &addend) != 1) break; // scans input into variable to be added to sum
        
        if (addend != 9999) {
            sum += addend; // Adds addend to sum
            ++counter;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for (addend; addend != 9999; ++counter) {
```

where `counter` is not initialized before using.

The fix:  `unsigned int counter = 0;`

The only thing to address beyond that is that the `counter` value is being incremented once beyond what it should, giving wrong results.

eg, for these inputs:

```
4+6+8+9
```

Average should be `27/4 == 6`, but `counter == 5` after only 4 entries,
Average is computed as `27/5 == 5`

To address this
change `average = sum / counter;`
to     `average = sum / (counter - 1);`

Beyond that, integer division results in rounding, so unless the numerator contains all of the prime factors of the denominator, the result will invoke integer rounding.  If that is a concern, floating point variables should be considered.

Comment: none of the solutions have worked so far. is there anything else i can try?

Comment: @jtlwsejiejyj445 -  I've updated my answer.  `counter` is off by `1` when last input (before `9999`) is entered.